# Deploy client and server separately of mean/ mern stack app

Tags: deployment, mean-stack, mern

What would be best practise for Mean/ Mern Stack app to host full stack or use cdn for client side and server side on other platforms.

Answer (score 0):

It's usually best to use CDN's as they will cause your client-side to render faster due to being hosted all over the world.